# Loading vc++ assembly to C#

Tags: visual-studio, dll, .net-assembly

I have to write C++ program which passes tests written in C# (both must be in the same solution but different projects in Visual Studio).
I managed to create C++ project (win32 dll) but I can't test it.
Here is the reason :
in testing project I have this line :

```
private Assembly Assembly { get { return Assembly.Load("Exercise"); } }
```

where "Exercise" is project that i have to create in C++.

I can't add reference to my .dll generated by C++ project because of error :

> A reference to Exercise could not be added

To simplify let's assume that my Exercise project ( this one in C++) contains only files required to create .dll and file Exercise.cpp but that didn't help.

My question is : how to load assembly(?) from vc++ to C# UnitTest project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to load native c++ to C# project.
Answer to that problem is create CLR C++ project.